# Universal enveloping algebra of sl2

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am currently trying to prove that $x-1$ is not invertible in the universal enveloping algebra $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F}))$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{F})$, but I still struggle with understanding how $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F}))$ itself looks.
Let $x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ denote the standard basis of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{F})$. I tried working with the corresponding PBW basis. First I took an arbitrary element $u=\sum\nolimits_{ijk}\lambda_{ijk}x^{i}h^{j}y^{k}$ with $(x-1)u=1$ and tried to show that such an $u$ doesn´t exist.
\begin{align*}1&=(x-1)u \\
&=(x-1)(\sum\nolimits_{ijk}\lambda_{ijk}x^{i}h^{j}y^{k}) \\
&=(\sum\nolimits_{ijk}\lambda_{ijk}x^{i+1}h^{j}y^{k})-(\sum\nolimits_{ijk}\lambda_{ijk}x^{i}h^{j}y^{k}) \\
&= \dots\end{align*}
But I am not even sure if this is the correct way working in $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F}))$.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: This looks alright, just use the fact that the $x^iy^jh^k$, $0\leq i,j,k$, form a basis (Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt), and compare coefficients (in particular those coefficients with $i$ maximal).

Comment: Ok, so I take $i$ maximal. Then the second sum contains no $\lambda_{ijk}x^{i+1}h^{j}y^{k}$, so $1=(\sum\nolimits_{jk}\lambda_{ijk}x^{i+1}h^{j}y^{k})+c$, with the sum nonzero and $i+1\neq0$ and c also a linear combination of $x^{i}h^{j}y^{k}$. But then 1 would be linear dependent to the $x^{i}h^{j}y^{k}$ with at least one exponent nonzero, what is not. That means such an $u$ can  not exist. Correct?